# Specify the package name to call this app

Tags: android, android-intent

my app AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.test.orc.IdentifyIdcards"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
      <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com_test_orc_IdentifyIdcards" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

so  any app can call my app by

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("start_photo_identify_picture_activity");
startActivity(intent);
```

but I limit only the package name is `com.test.idcard` can call my app, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the way that they start your app .If they call your app and your app started with `startActivityForResult`, you can have the caller by using `getCallingActivity()` and with that, you can have the package name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `<permission>` on the manifest, Specifically you want the

> android:protectionLevel="signature"

[Read more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)